# Is there a typescript/react-based library for creating form with logical and/or fields

Tags: javascript, reactjs, typescript, forms, search

Is there a typescript/react-based library for creating form with logical and/or fields? User should be able to dynamically add fields and set a logical relation (AND/OR/NOT) between them.

Thank you for any input.

Comment: Hard to tell exactly what you're looking for, but is this up your alley [react query builder](https://react-querybuilder.js.org/)? Or [react awesome query builder](https://github.com/ukrbublik/react-awesome-query-builder?tab=readme-ov-file)?

Comment: Yes, exactly, something like this. Thank you very much!